# Как лучше всего разметить шаблон сайта?

Tags: html, css, html5

Доброго времени суток. Подскажите как лучше всего в HTML разметить такой шаблон? Таблицей?

[image: Шаблон]

Comment: таблицы, флекс, float

Comment: flex для этой задачи отлично подоёдёт, у вас будет внешний контейнер горизонтальный flex и внутренние флексы для вертикальных списков.

Comment: Если [поддержка браузеров](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid) не супер тотальна, то идеально подойдёт [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/). Flexbox он 1D, а CSS Grid как раз 2D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот основная идея такой разметки на **Flex**.
Полностью подгонять код под ваш вопрос не стал, так как нужна ваша работа.

```css
.horisontal-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.vertical-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.row-item {
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 2px;
}

.full-block {
  height: calc(20px * 4 + 4px * 3);
  width: 200px;
  background-color: orange;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="horisontal-container">
  <div class="full-block">

  </div>

  <div class="vertical-container">
    <div class="row-item"> </div>
    <div class="row-item"> </div>
    <div class="row-item"> </div>
    <div class="row-item"> </div>
  </div>

  <div class="vertical-container">
    <div class="row-item"> </div>
    <div class="row-item"> </div>
    <div class="row-item"> </div>
    <div class="row-item"> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Код достаточно адаптивный, и будет работать на разных разрешениях экрана.
Для полной адаптивности надо использовать `media query`.

Comment: Мне кажется недостаточно адаптивный. Лучше убрать height: calc(20px * 4 + 4px * 3) так как мы привязываемся к количеству, размеру и отступам и добавить просто align-items: stretch; на .horisontal-container

Comment: Вешать вычисления на CSS с магическими числами...

Comment: @l2banners хорошая идея, вечером попробую, мне самому этот cacl не понравился, пробовал height: 100% но не сработал.